# How to Integrate Blue Imp File Upload to CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Wa are using CakePHP and need to integrate the Blue Imp file upload libraries.  Has anyone successfully integrated these?  If so, did you setup the upload to store files on the database or file system?  Can you share examples of such an integration?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I integrated the BlueImp file upload functionality in php. Please find the following component and the element to use.

```
<?php
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Class 5.9.1
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 * Created By: Arun Jain
 */
App::import('Core', 'Inflector');
class UploadComponent extends Component
{

protected $options;

function __construct($options=null) {
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/attachments/files/',
        'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
        'param_name' => 'files',
        // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
        // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
        'delete_type' => 'POST',
        // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
        // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
        'max_file_size' => null,
        'min_file_size' => 1,
        'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
        'max_number_of_files' => null,
        // Set the following option to false to enable resumable uploads:
        'discard_aborted_uploads' => true,
        // Set to true to rotate images based on EXIF meta data, if available:
        'orient_image' => false,
        'image_versions' => array(
            // Uncomment the following version to restrict the size of
            // uploaded images. You can also add additional versions with
            // their own upload directories:
            /*
            'large' => array(
                'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
                'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
                'max_width' => 1920,
                'max_height' => 1200,
                'jpeg_quality' => 95
            ),
            */
            'thumbnail' => array(
                'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/attachments/thumbnails/',
                'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/attachments/thumbnails/',
                'max_width' => 80,
                'max_height' => 80
            )
        )
    );
    if (is_array($options)) {
        $this->options = array_replace_recursive($this->options, $options);
    }
}

protected function getFullUrl() {
    return
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://').
        (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].'@' : '').
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 443 ||
        $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 80 ? '' : ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']))).
        substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/'));
}

protected function set_file_delete_url($file) {
    $file->delete_url = $this->options['script_url']
        .'?file='.rawurlencode($file->name);
    $file->delete_type = $this->options['delete_type'];
    if ($file->delete_type !== 'DELETE') {
        $file->delete_url .= '&_method=DELETE';
    }
}

protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
    $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
    if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.') {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $file_name;
        $file->size = filesize($file_path);
        $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
        foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
            if (is_file($options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
                $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                    .rawurlencode($file->name);
            }
        }
        $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
        return $file;
    }
    return null;
}

protected function get_file_objects() {
    return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
        array($this, 'get_file_object'),
        scandir($this->options['upload_dir'])
    )));
}

protected function create_scaled_image($file_name, $options) {
    $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
    $new_file_path = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
    list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
    if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
        return false;
    }
    $scale = min(
        $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
        $options['max_height'] / $img_height
    );
    if ($scale >= 1) {
        if ($file_path !== $new_file_path) {
            return copy($file_path, $new_file_path);
        }
        return true;
    }
    $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
    $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
    $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
            $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
                $options['jpeg_quality'] : 75;
            break;
        case 'gif':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif ($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagegif';
            $image_quality = null;
            break;
        case 'png':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            @imagealphablending($new_img, false);
            @imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
            $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagepng';
            $image_quality = isset($options['png_quality']) ?
                $options['png_quality'] : 9;
            break;
        default:
            $src_img = null;
    }
    $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img,
        $src_img,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $new_width,
        $new_height,
        $img_width,
        $img_height
    ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
    // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
    @imagedestroy($src_img);
    @imagedestroy($new_img);
    return $success;
}

protected function has_error($uploaded_file, $file, $error) {
    if ($error) {
        return $error;
    }
    if (!preg_match($this->options['accept_file_types'], $file->name)) {
        return 'acceptFileTypes';
    }
    if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
        $file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);
    } else {
        $file_size = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
    }
    if ($this->options['max_file_size'] && (
            $file_size > $this->options['max_file_size'] ||
            $file->size > $this->options['max_file_size'])
        ) {
        return 'maxFileSize';
    }
    if ($this->options['min_file_size'] &&
        $file_size < $this->options['min_file_size']) {
        return 'minFileSize';
    }
    if (is_int($this->options['max_number_of_files']) && (
            count($this->get_file_objects()) >= $this->options['max_number_of_files'])
        ) {
        return 'maxNumberOfFiles';
    }
    return $error;
}

protected function upcount_name_callback($matches) {
    $index = isset($matches[1]) ? intval($matches[1]) + 1 : 1;
    $ext = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';
    return ' ('.$index.')'.$ext;
}

protected function upcount_name($name) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/(?:(?: \(([\d]+)\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/',
        array($this, 'upcount_name_callback'),
        $name,
        1
    );
}

protected function trim_file_name($name, $type) {
    // Remove path information and dots around the filename, to prevent uploading
    // into different directories or replacing hidden system files.
    // Also remove control characters and spaces (\x00..\x20) around the filename:
    $file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
    // Add missing file extension for known image types:
    if (strpos($file_name, '.') === false &&
        preg_match('/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)/', $type, $matches)) {
        $file_name .= '.'.$matches[1];
    }
    if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
        while(is_file($this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
            $file_name = $this->upcount_name($file_name);
        }
    }
    return $file_name;
}

protected function orient_image($file_path) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($file_path);
    $orientation = intval(@$exif['Orientation']);
    if (!in_array($orientation, array(3, 6, 8))) { 
        return false;
    }
    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
    switch ($orientation) {
          case 3:
            $image = @imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
            break;
          case 6:
            $image = @imagerotate($image, 270, 0);
            break;
          case 8:
            $image = @imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    $success = imagejpeg($image, $file_path);
    // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
    @imagedestroy($image);
    return $success;
}

protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error) {
    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->name = $this->trim_file_name($name, $type);
    $file->size = intval($size);
    $file->type = $type;
    $error = $this->has_error($uploaded_file, $file, $error);
    if (!$error && $file->name) {
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file->name;
        $append_file = !$this->options['discard_aborted_uploads'] &&
            is_file($file_path) && $file->size > filesize($file_path);
        clearstatcache();
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
            if ($append_file) {
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                    FILE_APPEND
                );
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
            }
        } else {
            // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
            file_put_contents(
                $file_path,
                fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
            );
        }
        $file_size = filesize($file_path);
        if ($file_size === $file->size) {
            if ($this->options['orient_image']) {
                $this->orient_image($file_path);
            }
            $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                if ($this->create_scaled_image($file->name, $options)) {
                    if ($this->options['upload_dir'] !== $options['upload_dir']) {
                        $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                            .rawurlencode($file->name);
                    } else {
                        clearstatcache();
                        $file_size = filesize($file_path);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
            unlink($file_path);
            $file->error = 'abort';
        }
        $file->size = $file_size;
        $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
    } else {
        $file->error = $error;
    }
    return $file;
}

public function get() {
    $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
        basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
    if ($file_name) {
        $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
    } else {
        $info = $this->get_file_objects();
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($info);
}

public function post() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
        return $this->delete();
    }
    $upload = isset($_FILES[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
        $_FILES[$this->options['param_name']] : null;
    $info = array();
    if ($upload && is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
        // param_name is an array identifier like "files[]",
        // $_FILES is a multi-dimensional array:
        foreach ($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
            $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                $upload['tmp_name'][$index],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'][$index],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : $upload['size'][$index],
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : $upload['type'][$index],
                $upload['error'][$index]
            );
        }
    } elseif ($upload || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'])) {
        // param_name is a single object identifier like "file",
        // $_FILES is a one-dimensional array:
        $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
            isset($upload['tmp_name']) ? $upload['tmp_name'] : null,
            isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : (isset($upload['name']) ?
                    $upload['name'] : null),
            isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : (isset($upload['size']) ?
                    $upload['size'] : null),
            isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : (isset($upload['type']) ?
                    $upload['type'] : null),
            isset($upload['error']) ? $upload['error'] : null
        );
    }
    header('Vary: Accept');
    $json = json_encode($info);
    $redirect = isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) ?
        stripslashes($_REQUEST['redirect']) : null;
    if ($redirect) {
        header('Location: '.sprintf($redirect, rawurlencode($json)));
        return;
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) &&
        (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json') !== false)) {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
    } else {
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
    }
    echo $json;
}

public function delete() {
    $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
        basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
    $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
    $success = is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.' && unlink($file_path);
    if ($success) {
        foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
            $file = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
            if (is_file($file)) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($success);
}

}
```

And your element should looks like it:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS Toolkit styles -->
<?php echo $this->Html->css('fileuploads/bootstrap.min');?>
<!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes     -->
<?php echo $this->Html->css('fileuploads/bootstrap-responsive.min');?>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><?php echo $this->Html->css('fileuploads/bootstrap-ie6.min');?>        <![endif]-->
<!-- Bootstrap Image Gallery styles -->
<?php echo $this->Html->css('fileuploads/bootstrap-image-gallery.min');?>
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress      bars -->
<?php echo $this->Html->css('fileuploads/jquery.fileupload-ui');?>
<!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><?php echo $this->Html->script('html5');?></script><![endif]-->
```

Add files...
                    
                
                
                    
                    Start upload
                
                
                    
                    Cancel upload
                
                
                    
                    Delete

```
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>    
</div>
<!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
<div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-image"></div></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon-download"></i>
        <span>Download</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
        <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
        <span>Slideshow</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
        <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
        <span>Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
        <span>Next</span>
        <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>

        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
        <td>
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    {% } else { %}
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
        <button class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
        </button>
    {% } %}</td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-download fade">
    {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
        {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
```

```
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/vendor/jquery.ui.widget');?>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/tmpl.min');?>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing 
functionality -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/load-image.min');?>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/canvas-to-blob.min');?>
<!-- Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script(array('fileuploads/bootstrap.min', 'fileuploads/bootstrap-image-gallery.min'));?>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/jquery.iframe-transport');?>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/jquery.fileupload');?>
<!-- The File Upload image processing plugin -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/jquery.fileupload-ip');?>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/jquery.fileupload-ui');?>
<!-- The localization script -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/locale');?>
<!-- The main application script -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/main');?>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE8+ -->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><?php echo $this->Html->script('fileuploads/cors/jquery.xdr-transport');?><!  [endif]-->
```

Comment: You can download this plugin from: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/