# CakePHP ajaxupload with Uploader

Tags: ajax, cakephp, upload, uploader, input-field

I want to upload multiple pictures using this CakePHP-Plugin, which I use to attach uploads to the model:
http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader
Unfortunately the documentation isn't very helpful on this. My plan is to submit the files one by one to circumvent the problems, which could arise if multiple bigger pictures are uploaded at once. What I need to do (at least I hope so) is to send a JSON-Request containing the local file-path and wait for the callback. How can I get the local filenames via javascript using an input field (with html5's muliple= multiple)?
Another question would be, if there could be any problems, of which I haven't thought yet. I'm not sure how the callback-mechanic will work, as the data send is just a text and the upload itself handled by the plugin.

Edit:
This is what I tried without using ajax. While this works in some occacions with multiple small files, it doesn't sometimes with multiple bigger images and also does not through back any errors.

```
    public function add($album_id = null, $album_title = null) {
    $this->set('album_id', $album_id);
    $this->set('album_title', $album_title);                
    // debug($this->data);
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $data['Picture']["album_id"]= $album_id;
        foreach ($data['Picture']['files'] as $file){
            $tmp_data = $data;              
            $tmp_data['Picture']['files']="";
            $tmp_data['Picture']['file']=$file;
            debug ($tmp_data);  
            $this->Picture->saveAll($tmp_data, array('deep' => true));
        }           
    }        
    }
```

Comment: That module is very well-documented. I understood every step of the module you linked at a glance. You should familiarize yourself with the framework you're asking about first. Or the technology in general. What you're trying to do is pretty easy, frankly. Heck, jQuery could solve this for you. >_>

Some code samples and a brief description of what you've already tried, please?

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/ is a good ajaxupload. You can download its component I wrote from the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401756/how-to-integrate-blue-imp-file-upload-to-cakephp/11407169#11407169